# Why performance degrade from poi 3.13 to 3.17 when we use autoSizeColumn api

Tags: java, apache-poi

Does any one have idea why this much performance degrade came when we move from poi 3.13 to 3.17 for autoSizeColumn.

POI 3.13 for 100 000 rows and 55 columns taking hardly 20 seconds, but in POI 3.17 for same data it's taking more than 400 seconds.

Comment: Because of improvements in [SheetUtil.java version 17 SheetUtil.getCellWidth](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_17_FINAL/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/util/SheetUtil.java?view=markup#l122) vs. [SheetUtil.java version 13 SheetUtil.getCellWidth](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_3_13_FINAL/src/java/org/apache/poi/ss/util/SheetUtil.java?view=markup#l99). The improvements are fixing issues in calculating the best fit width dependent on different cell contents but those improvements costs performance.

Comment: Thank you Axel, If we are doing manually setColumnWidth by calculating max columns chars length and taking 2 chars buffer and multiplying with 256 then it's too much faster. any idea poi is going to fix/fixed in any newer versions.

Comment: If the process you are describing is sufficient for you, the do so. But I would not expect that the `apache poi` developer team will go back to this simple process since it is **not** sufficient for most of the other users since much things are not taken into account, rich text having different fonts and formatted numbers and.... I am not part of the `apache poi` developer team so this is only my humble opinion.